# Java container managed transactions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, ejb

I have encountered a problem and I can't figure out the cause. For the rest of the post, we shall assume that every transaction is container managed and that we use jboss AS 7.X. We have three stateless ejb's. We will call them RestEJB, IntEJB and ProviderEJB. The provider base methods are:

```
save(){
    return getEm().merge(ob);
```

The core line of the load method is:

```
load(){
    Query query = getEm().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
```

The base order is something along the lines of RestEJB -> IntEJB -> ProviderEJB.

Now, depending on the order of the operations, we may receive a ARJUNA012117 error in jboss.

The problematic code is this:

```
RestEJB.someMethod(){
    item = IntEJB.save(item)
}

IntEJB.save(Item item){
    ...
        ProviderEJB.save(item)
        return ProviderEJB.load(item)
    }
```

However if we rewrite it like this:

```
RestEJB.someMethod(){
    item = IntEJB.save(item)
    item = IntEJB.load(item)
}

IntEJB.save(){
    ...
    return ProviderEJB.save(item)
}

IntEJB.load(){
    ...
    return ProviderEJB.load(item)
}
```

Then everything will work properly. In the above examples, item represents the same Object. Thus, the save and load are done on the same object (which may in turn trigger other fetches). There is no code written between save and load in either of the examples.

The question is this: How come it works when we move the load one ejb up as opposed to loading at the same level ejb as the save?
Since we use hibernate, all the code will be commited to the database only after we exit RestEJB.

Comment: Your code fragment is not making much sense, please show the actual code, even if you are changing the names

Comment: fixed it. I won't show the actual code as I do not own it

Comment: A quick fix would be to add @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) on the ProviderEJB.save(item) to force it to execute on a different transaction

Comment: yes, I agree. If it executes in a different transaction then it will see the changes. However, why doesn't the load work in the same transaction as the save?

Comment: When loading, it normally tries to refresh the state of the entity, either from cache or database, and since the current transaction is not complete, the save is not yet committed

Comment: I understand. So it is best to rely on updated proxy data only if we are at least one transaction level above the current one.